# Visual block selection using mouse in Neovim

Tags: neovim, mouse

Is it possible? I `set mouse=a`, go to **VISUAL BLOCK** mode but when I click and move pointer, neovim falls into **VISUAL** and mouse selects character-wise.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have `set mousemodel=extend` it's simply `<RightMouse>`.